# button_to_remote :html => {}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Greetings,

I am trying to get a button to generate with id="view-blog-1-comments" and it seems the button_to_remote function is ignoring my call.  Could some one set me straight on what I am doing wrong here.

> blog_comments_path(blog), 
>           :html => {:id => "view-blog-#{blog.id}-comments"},
>       :method => :get %>

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button_to_remote(name, options = {}, html_options = {})

is the method signature, so you need to rearrange your syntax to this:

> button_to_remote 'View Comments', :url => blog_comments_path(blog), {:method => :get}, :id => "view-blog-#{blog.id}-comments"

Comment: Thank you.  I actually had to change it to {:url => blog_comment_path(blog), :method=>:get}, :id =>"view-blog-#{blog.id}-comments".  But your comment made me remember about how ruby collects key/value pairs together in function calls.